# Running sess.run (tensorflow) in parallel using python multiprocessing on windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I have successfully trained a CNN and saved the model using tf.train.Saver() object.

In my production code, I need to load the model and run the predict op to get the prediction. I am able to do the same with tf.Saver and it's restore method.

Now I need to run this predict op in parallel. I am using Python's joblib's Parallel method to get the work done. I am running on windows 7.
Now the problem is when I use threading as backend it runs fine. But I wanna use mutliprocessing so as to assign cpu affinity.

I tried passing in session object but, sess.run command gets hang forever.
so other option is to create a new session in each worker process. If I create a graph in worker process then the subsequent creation of the graph changes the op name and  I can't restore my weights into the graph.

Can any1 help